# Page not found error while deploying django app on centos7 using nginx and uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, centos7, uwsgi, vps

I'm trying to deploy my django app on a centOS7 server using VPS with nginx and uwsgi, following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_17jALtLbQ&feature=youtu.be. The server is up and running i.e., the homepage (welcome to nginx) is working but when I navigate to a different page it tells me "page not found".

Previously, I also tried using Apache following this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-centos-7. But it tells me "you don't have permission to access /url/".

Following is the code for /etc/nginx/sites-available/sitename:

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/main.sock;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }

        location /static/ {
                alias /var/www/supplychain/Supply_Chain_Proj/static/;
        }
}
```

And this is my /etc/uwsgi/apps-available/sitename.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
vhost = true
plugins = python
socket = /tmp/main.sock
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 4
wsgi-file = /var/www/supplychain/Supply_Chain_Proj/supply_chain/wsgi.py
virtualenv = /var/www/venv/site
chdir = /var/www/supplychain/Supply_Chain_Proj
touch-reload = /var/www/supplychain/Supply_Chain_Proj/reload
env = DJANGO_ENV=production
env = ALLOWED_HOSTS=*
```